# launch application in ios real device

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium

This is the main  error :

> **Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException` : Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details.**

Original error :

> **An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.**

Original error:

> **Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id d1f93a4330d01b0cbf8dbf6e97116312fb1bc9c4 --bundle /Users/dpk/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app' exited with code 253'**

I want to launch app in ios device that is not working for me for that i need some solution and these error is generated while i am running the script which has been mentioned above.

Comment: Please add your question, details and how you generate these errors...

Comment: i want to launch app in ios device that is not working for me for that i need some solution and these error is generated while i am running the script which has been mentioned above

Comment: DesiredCapabilities cap =new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.3.1");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "myid");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "");cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/dpkDesktop/IntegrationApp.app");
  url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(url,cap);